# Laravel Controller not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm very new to the Laravel framework and am trying to load a simple controller in my browser to slowly get the hang of things.

I have a file that's titled users.php inside of the the laravel/app/controllers/ folder and it looks like this:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController 
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function action_index()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
```

In the routes.php file, I have

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
```

But, when I go to

```
http://localhost:8888/laravel/public/users
```

I'm greeted with a message that says "ReflectionException
Class UsersController does not exist"

[image]

I'm not sure if this is because I didn't install the mcrypt extension of PHP. But, when I checked the php.ini file on MAMP, it said that it was enabled. Upon entering

```
which PHP
```

in my terminal, it said /usr/bin/php. So, it might not be using the correct version of PHP.

I'm not entirely sure if this is a routes problem or if it's stemming from an absence of a vital PHP extension.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Route::controller method to reference your Controller:

```
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

...and rename your file (as Cryode mentions ) to be `TestController.php`.

Note - if you want to use the filename as test.php, then you will need to use [composer](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-composer) to update the autoload settings.

Finally, the format of names for Controller methods changed in Laravel 4, try renaming the method

```
public function action_index() {}
```

to be

```
public function getIndex() {}
```

the `get` represents a HTTP GET request... the same applies for `post` (HTTP POST) and `any` (GET or POST.. )

Comment: Says command not found. And what is this about having to update classes after introducing new ones? Why exactly is Laravel better than CodeIgniter again?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong about the updating of classes after adding new ones.. that doesn't apply here -  I'll update the above.  You still need to change your method names

Comment: @Lance your problem was with the use of Route::get.. have a look above

Comment: @Lance clarified and tested the point regarding composer, updated above#

Comment: Thanks a bunch, dude. I knew it was something simple like that! Btw, from your experiences, do you find Laravel to be better than CI?

Comment: Cool!  To be honest, never used CI :)  I do really like Laravel's routing and Eloquent features, but I won't be able to give you a solid basis for comparison between the two

Comment: Laravel is better in a lot of ways, and the same in others. Use whichever suits your project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with that part of Laravel's source, so I'm not entirely certain that this is the issue, but your controller file name should match the controller class name, including capitalization.

So `users.php` should be `UsersController.php`. Now, when I do this myself on purpose, I get a "No such file or directory" error on an `include()` call, so that's why I'm not certain that's the sole cause of your problem. But it may be a start.