# PHPUnit 3.7 can't find Controller Classes in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, composer-php

### Setup 1: Echoing back from the route works in PHPUnit

*routes.php*

```
Route::get('signup', function(){
    return "Hello World!";
});
```

*/tests/SignupTest.php*

```
class SignupTest extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex(){
        $this->call('GET', 'signup');
        $this->assertResponseOK();
    }
}
```

Running PHPUnit returns the following:

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

### Setup 2: But PHPUnit can't find the Signup Controller when I route to it

*routes.php*

```
Route::get('signup', array('uses' => 'Signup@process'));
```

*/app/controllers/Signup.php*

```
class Signup extends BaseController {
    public function process(){
        echo  "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

*/tests/SignupTest.php*

```
class SignupTest extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex(){
        $this->call('GET', 'signup');
        $this->assertResponseOK();
    }
}
```

PHPUnit returns the following:

```
There was 1 error:

1) SignupTest::testIndex
ReflectionException: Class Signup does not exist

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:476
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:416
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:423
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:77
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:50
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:900
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:118
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:964
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:934
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:677
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:652
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:82
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:319
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:74
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/app/tests/SignupTest.php:12

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

**Setup information:**

- Laravel 4.1
- PHPUnit 3.7.28
- Both installed by Composer
- MAMP running PHP 5.4.4 on Mac OS X 10.8

I don't think I've changed anything in the core/config files of Laravel or PHPUnit.

**Things I've tried:**

I found a few answers about this type of issue (both on SO and other sites), where the answers suggested fixing mistakes in names of class/file/method, e.g.:

[Laravel Controller not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643016/laravel-controller-not-working)

I don't think this is an issue here, because I've checked all the names. *Also it returns "Hello World!" as expected for both the above routes when tested in a browser*, suggesting that the route is working fine in Laravel. Problem seems to be with PHPUnit.

**My Question: Why can't PHPUnit find the Signup Class in app/controllers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assumed that because there was a `phpunit.xml` file in the basic Laravel install, that PHPUnit would know about it. That assumption turned out to be incorrect.

**The Problem**

PHPUnit wasn't loading `phpunit.xml`, which meant the bootstrap file in `bootstrap/autoload.php` wasn't being loaded, so PHPUnit had no idea where any of the class files were, including `Signup.php`.

**The Solution**

I added the file path to `phpunit.xml` in the `--configuration` switch when I ran PHPUnit:

```
--configuration /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/phpunit.xml
```

**General Advice**

If PHPUnit tells you it can't find a class, check that it's loading `phpunit.xml` and/or your bootstrap file. Make sure your `phpunit.xml` file points correctly to your bootstrap file and that your bootstrap file is configured correctly to load the required classes.

Also, as pointed out in my question, problems can also be caused by inconsistencies between class/file/method names.